# Parse pages from html code href in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html, which contains the below code:

```
<a href="?page=5" title="Go to last page">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Last page</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">Last »</span>
          </a>
```

could someone please help me in getting the last page number (`5` in this case) using Beautiful Soup?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split` on `href=` property:

```
last_page = soup.find('a')['href'].split('=')[-1]
print(last_page)
```

Prints:

```
5
```

---

Or (to select `<a>` tag with `title="Go to last page"`:

```
last_page = soup.find('a', title='Go to last page')['href'].split('=')[-1]
print(last_page)
```